# Show that for every $\varepsilon>0$ there exists an open dense set $G \subset \mathbb{R}$ whose Lebesgue measure is at most $\varepsilon$

Tags: measure-theory

$$G= \bigcup _{n \in \mathbb{N}} I_n$$

where we let $I_n<(q_n- \epsilon 2^{-n-1}, q_n + \varepsilon 2^{-n-1} )$

Why have we chosen $I_n$ to be this?

What is the significance of $2^{-n-1}$?

The proof  goes on to say $\sum^\infty _{n=1} \varepsilon 2 \cdot 2^{-n-1} = \varepsilon$.

Where does this last step come from?

Comment: Sum of infinite geometric series.

Comment: Ok, where does $I_n$ come from?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We enumerate the rationals as $q_1,q_2,q_3,\dots$. The interval $I_n$ described in the OP contains $q_n$. so the union of the $I_n$ contains all the rationals.

The width of the interval $I_n$ is $2\epsilon\cdot 2^{-n-1}$, that is, $\epsilon\cdot 2^{-n}$. The sum of the widths of the $I_n$ is therefore
$$\epsilon \cdot \frac{1}{2}+\epsilon\cdot \frac{1}{2^2}+\epsilon\cdot \frac{1}{2^3}+\cdots.$$
This is an infinite geometric series with first term $\frac{\epsilon}{2}$ and common ratio $\frac{1}{2}$. By the usual formula, the series has sum $\epsilon$.

There is in a sense nothing special about the choice of $\epsilon \cdot 2^{-n}$ for the widths of the $I_n$. If $(a_n)$ is any sequence of positive reals such that $\sum_1^\infty a_n$ converges, say to $s$, we could have chosen the width of $I_n$ to be $\epsilon \cdot \frac{a_n}{s}$.